# <A href> adding " to URL

Tags: html

I'm trying to link two key phrases from my homepage to the relevant service page of the website - Sounds easy enough, but for some reason it won't work and I'm clueless as to what the problem is.

```
<a href="http://something-nice.co.uk/service/vintage-rustic-wedding-furniture-hire/">rustic furniture</a>

<a href="http://something-nice.co.uk/service/rustic-table-chair-hire/">tables & chairs</a>
```

The page I'm trying to do this on can be found [here](http://something-nice.co.uk).

But for some reason after clicking the links - it goes through to a 404 page.
I've noticed that after clicking onto the link the URL reads: http://something-nic...ble-chair-hire" <---- With the extra "

So instead of copying the URL, I went back and manually typed it out into the a href tag. 
BUT IT STILL DOESN'T WORK!!!

What am I doing wrong here people?

Comment: I don't see the problem on the page you've linked.  Is it a specific link?

Comment: Link appears to work fine. Can you [edit] your question and try to add a snippet (clicking on the `<>` icon in the editor) and try to reproduce it?

Comment: I haven't found anything its working fine whats your error bro?

Comment: Can you please post the whole code?

Comment: Please copy/paste the original code and use the **`{}`** tool to format it as code. What you have not is not possible to debug

Answer (score 0):

I fond a &quot; tag in the href, maybe that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you added an extra space between "<" and "a" that's why it's not working. After applying this changes the code works just fine in my chrome browser.

```
<a href="http://something-nice.co.uk/service/vintage-rustic-wedding-furniture-hire/">rustic furniture

<a href="http://something-nice.co.uk/service/rustic-table-chair-hire/">tables & chairs
```

Comment: I think that space was added because he didn't get it to display properly otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback